# Controlling multiple Button's Properties within ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have 18 Buttons within a Uniform grid on my main WPF window.  I need to modify many of the Button's Properties and Command both when the program loads and during operation.  In other words, when the program first starts, a configuration is selected that affects the layout.  Later that could change further depending on how the program operates.  I'm trying to consolidate all logic within a ViewModel.  So the simple question is - how to best implement this design?

A few ideas:

- Could use traditional bindings.  This works except you could end up with 100's of them.  Also, would have ugly logic within each property - i.e. if config1 then background is red, else if config2 or 3 then background is blue.
- Could limit the number of bindings with ValueConverters and CommandParameters but then you have even messier property logic.
- Could bind to the Button's style.  This works to simplify the property settings but you end up with a bunch of styles to mess with.  Also doesn't work well after the program is loaded (I don't think you can change a Style after it's applied).
- Could have a different Uniform grid (each with a set of 18 buttons) for each configuration, then only show the selected one.  This simplifies the property logic but messes up the XAML.
- Could pass the Button objects themselves to the ViewModel.  Not sure how to implement this plus I think it breaks the MVVM pattern.  Might be the easiest if I knew how to do it.

I'm at a loss for an elegant solution.  I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing.  Any ideas are appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done in that case:

Since you have several properties you want to bind to on each button, including a command, I would make a separate, small ViewModel (`MyButtonViewModel`) for each button, which includes the properties and command.

Then, in the primary ViewModel, I would create a collection (`ObservableCollection<MyButtonViewModel>`) of your button view models, and populate it using some simple looping (or LINQ) code.

Then, in the View, I would declare an `ItemsControl` to use an `ItemPanel` of `UniformGrid`.  Then, For the `ItemTemplate`, I'd define the button to bind to the properties in `MyButtonViewModel`.

Simple, small, and elegant IMO.

Let me know if you need any clarification,
B

Comment: Interesting concept.  Thanks for the input.  I appreciate the help.  I'll work on the idea and let you know how it turns out.